# Classes with Identical names returned from Online tool causes error

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I Have used an online tool to build the classes I need to serialise json returned from a web service. The json contains an item which may be a single object or an json array or could be empty. The online tool adds to classes to handle this

The json element that is causing the issue is;

> "customData":{"customData":[{ "key" : "Vehicle", "value" : "A123ABC"
>   }, { "key" : "Trailer", "value" : "T123" }, { "key" : "Job Number",
>   "value" : "123456@1" }

The classes as output from the tool:

```
<DataContract()>
Public Class CustomData
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property key As String
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property value As String
End Class

Public Class CustomData
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property customData As CustomData()
End Class
```

I can see why the code is built in this fashion but as is it causes an error because of the duplication,  how do I overcome this?

Comment: The name of the classes shouldn't matter apart from perhaps the outermost class. The important thing is the name of the variables. To overcome the name conflict you could for instance name the first class in your question `CustomDataInner`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply I have made the change as suggested. But now I am getting another error Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''.  as I understand it this is caused by by inner json elements.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error message you're getting along with your code that deserializes the JSON, showing on which line the error is thrown. If the JSON has changed in any way please include that as well.

Comment: The JSON snippet that you've posted is missing the main body, perhaps you need a third class? Can you show us a more complete (but not too long) JSON snippet?